# Numpy: get array where index greater than value and condition is true

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([6,5,4,3,4,5,6])
```

Now I want to get all elements which are greater than 4 but also have in index value greater than 2.
The way that I have found to do that was the following:

```
a[2:][a[2:]>4]
```

Is there a better or more readable way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**:
This is a simplified version. In reality the indexing is done with arithmetic operation over several variables like this:

```
a[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:][a[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:]>4]
```

`trainPredict` ist a numpy array, `look_back` an integer.
I wanted to see if there is an established way or how others do that.

Comment: Are you looking for the elements, the indices of the elements (in the original array, presumably), or a mask for the elements?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am looking for the elements on part of the array as shown in the sample: `a[2:][a[2:]>4]`

Comment: You should select the posted answer. It's about as concise and accurate as you can be.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is the same as that I have written in the question: `a[2:][a[2:]>4]`, just in three lines instead of one. If there is no other way, then I will have my answer and will select it.

Comment: The other ways I can think of are all much less efficient. I'll write an answer to prove it. The existing answer is a much cleaner way than the one-liner because it avoids redundant temp arrays.

Comment: @CodePope the code in your post seems like the standard/idiomatic way of doing things. One question, however: Is trainPredict a numpy array, a plain Python list, or something else entirely? It might also help if we could get a tiny bit more context, maybe an example of the 3 objects involved.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have updated the question

Comment: @CodePope you are using `len()` to find the number of arrays along the 0th dimension (`len(arr) == arr.shape[0]`), and not the total number of elements, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about the complexity of the slice and/or the number of conditions, you can always separate them:

```
a = np.array([6,5,4,3,4,5,6])

a_slice = a[2:]

cond_1 = a_slice > 4

res = a_slice[cond_1]
```

Is your example very simplified? There might be better solutions for more complex manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

[@AlexanderCécile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310124/2988730) is not only more legible than the one liner you posted, but is also removes the redundant computation of a temp array. Despite that, it does not appear to be any faster than your original approach.

The timings below are all run with a preliminary setup of

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0xDEADBEEF)
a = np.random.randint(8, size=N)
```

`N` varies from 1e3 to 1e8 in factors of 10. I tried four variants of the code:

1. CodePope: `result = a[2:][a[2:] > 4]`
2. AlexanderCécile: `s = a[2:]; result = s[s > 4]`
3. MadPhysicist1: `result = a[np.flatnonzero(a[2:]) + 2]`
4. MadPhysicist2: `result = a[(a > 4) & (np.arange(a.size) >= 2)]`

In all cases, the timing was obtained on the command line by running

```
python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0xDEADBEEF); a = np.random.randint(8, size=N)' '<X>'
```

Here, `N` was a power of 10 between 3 and 8, and `<X>` one of the expressions above. Timings are as follows:

[image]

Methods #1 and #2 are virtually indistinguishable. What is surprising is that in the range between ~5e3 and ~1e6 elements, method #3 seems to be slightly, but noticeably faster. I would not normally expect that from fancy indexing. Method #4 is of course going to be the slowest.

Here is the data, for completeness:

```
           CodePope  AlexanderCécile  MadPhysicist1  MadPhysicist2
1000       3.77e-06         3.69e-06       5.48e-06       6.52e-06
10000       4.6e-05         4.59e-05       3.97e-05       5.93e-05
100000     0.000484         0.000483         0.0004       0.000592
1000000     0.00513          0.00515        0.00503        0.00675
10000000     0.0529           0.0525         0.0617          0.102
100000000     0.657            0.658          0.782           1.09
```

Comment: Indeed, my answer only improves legibility. Since numpy array slices are views, the overheard of creating a new variable probably outweighs the small performance gain from not slicing twice.

Comment: Edit: In his updated code, however, separating the parts as in my answer may lead to an increase in performance since the numerical operations create new arrays.